# How to understand a Int-Proc entry, mentioned in client.mon file?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm dealing with a list of errors while trying to open a `*.w` file in the appBuilder. I managed to find a previous version of that file, which opens fine, and I see following differences between both files:

```
Per procedure segment information
---------------------------------
    File  Segment  #Segments  Total-Size
    ----  -------  ---------  ----------
    Good_version.w
    ...
        Int-Proc: 19    1     26232
    ...        
    Bad_version.w
    ...
        Int-Proc: 19    1     32712
```

As you can see, "Int-Proc" number 19 seems to be the one, exceeding the segment size (above 32K) and hence is the one causing the problem.

Now the obvious question: how can I know the meaning of "Int-Proc" number 19? I have some procedures inside my code but the number does not correspond with the total number of "Int-Proc" (very naïvely: I have 38 "Int-Proc" entries in client.mon but only 21 `End procedure.` entries in my source code).

**Edit**
The action to take in case of exceeding 32K limit is splitting the procedure, which grows too large, into smaller pieces. However, between `Bad_version.w` and `Good_version.w`, it seems that in total 5 procedures have been expanded, and I'd like to know which one I need to split.

Comment: The END statement does not require “procedure”. Just plain END is also valid. That might explain the discrepancy.

Comment: @TomBascom: I believe the situation is different: there are 25 procedures in my source code file and client.mon mentions 42 internal procedures, but after having done a compilation, the listing file contains 41 `END PROCEDURE.` lines, I believe the discrepancy is due to includes, not to other `END` lines.

Comment: You are likely correct. Like Stefan I have never actually used app builder. I know that it uses lots of pre-processors though.  FWIW, the 41 vs 42 issue seems to me to be likely to counting the "main" procedure as one and since that has neither a "procedure" nor and "end" there is now way to count it by grepping for something in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never used the AppBuilder.

[client.mon](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-manage-applications/page/R-code-execution-environment-statistics.html) is for r-code statistics, so I think that instead of .w there should be a .r there. The AppBuilder has a 32000 byte (= maximum size of a character variable) limit for internal procedures. 32000 new lines will also break the AppBuilder view, but compile to 0 bytes (or so).

I /thought/ the AppBuilder would complain about an internal procedure being too large upon selecting the procedure that is too large. If not you will need to get the /text/ content size of block of your .w between procedure and end procedure and you know which are your problem.

Something like:

```
def var lcw    as longchar  no-undo.
def var iprocs as integer   no-undo.
def var lcproc as longchar  no-undo.
def var cc     as character no-undo.
def var ic     as integer   no-undo.

cc = chr(1).

copy-lob from file "my.w" to lcw.

assign 
   lcw = replace( lcw, 'procedure ', cc )
   lcw = replace( lcw, 'end procedure', cc )
   iprocs = num-entries( lcw, cc )
   .

do ic = 1 to iprocs:

   lcproc = entry( ic, lcw, cc ).
   if length( lcproc ) > 31000 then
      message substring( lcproc, 1, 100 ) view-as alert-box.

end.
```

Intrigued by how the AppBuilder really complains:

- started the AppBuilder
- created a Smart Window
- opened the first procedure section (it was a trigger)
- added // some comment
- saved the .w
- opened the .w with Notepad++ and blew up // some comment to be larger than 32000 bytes

Opened .w with AppBuilder, endless errors.
Quit.

-> Added -debugalert to my shortcut.
On first error started debugger.
Debugger tries to start, but does not (remember the hidden procedures post)

-> Added -zn to my shortcut.
On first error started debugger.
It starts. While I cannot see any source code since I have not extracted the source code pls, I can see and view all variable and buffers.

Since I had blown up a trigger, the error reported _trg. Viewing _trg:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Include files and pre-processor expansions will also impact the compiled procedure size.

Comment: Yes, but not the size for the AppBuilder procedure buffer

Comment: You forget to mention one thing here: the `_tCode` attribute of the `_TRG` view indeed shows the code, which is causing the failure, but for me the most important thing to know is the name of the procedure, containing that piece of code. That information can be found in `_TRG._tEvent`, and that's the life saver :-)

Comment: You must admit that it's quite funny that an application "code parser" can be blown up, just by adding some comments :-)

Comment: I think that the main problem is that the code parser stems from 1998 (see http://oehive.org/VersionHistory) - a time in which a 32K block of source code may have beenconsidered ridiculously large. And as with all things in time, even though the AppBuilder could have been updated to use a longchar, Uncle Bob would definitely frown on your 32K block of source code as being plain rude.