# Is it possible to see the contents of the tables, used by appBuilder?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with appBuilder/procedure editor, release 11.6.

Recently, I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023829/how-to-understand-a-int-proc-entry-mentioned-in-client-mon-file) about a file, which could not be opened by the appBuilder. The answer as:

> Debug the appBuilder and check the contents of the _TRG table tupple the appBuilder is working with.

And indeed the content of that particular `_TRG` tupple solved my answer.

My reaction now is:

> If the content of a `_TRG` can explain why a particular problem arises, I would like to see the content of all `_TRG` tupples in order to avoid that problem happening in future.

In order to do this, I tried the "Data Administration" tool, "Dump data and definitions" (obviously after having chosen every possible database and after having checked the "Hidden tables" checkbox).
I also tried following piece of code in the procedure editor, but that didn't work too as the `_TRG` table seems nowhere to be known:

```
OUTPUT TO C:\Temp_Folder\_Trg.log.
FOR EACH _TRG:
    PUT UNFORMATTED _tEvent "|" _tCode.
END.
```

However, the `_TRG` tables seems not to be known.
Does anybody know what I can do in order to access this table and how to obtain all its contents?
By the way, the `_TRG` table contains a `_tEvent` column, mentioning the name of the erroneous procedure and it contains a `_tCode` column, containing the erroneous (too large) code, but there seems not to be a column, containing the `*.w` file, containing that procedure. In which table will I find this information and what's the link with the `_TRG` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What led you to believe that _trg is a database table? When you open a source file do you select something from a database or are you using a file explorer?

If you look at what you are viewing in the debugger:

[image]

You can see that this is a `temp-table`, which is one of a whole set of temp-tables which is populated upon opening a file.

Comment: In the question I refer to, you mentioned using "Dataview" in the debugger to open `_TRG` table, hence my mistake.